# Problema con mappedBy en Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

estoy haciendo una aplicación con Spring para mi TFG y me he encontrado con este problema al que no le encuentro el porqué.

Tengo estas tres clases:

**ONG**

```
package com.aiddonAPI.ong;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.*;
import com.aiddonAPI.identificador.Identificador;

@Table(name="ONGs")
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name="SequenceONG", initialValue=0)
public class ONG implements Serializable{
    @GeneratedValue(generator="SequenceONG") 
    @Id
    @Column(name="idONG")
    Long idONG;
    @Column(name="nombreONG", unique=true)
    String nombreONG;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="ong")
    List<Identificador>  identificadoresONG;
    @Column(name="urlONG", unique=true)
    String urlONG;
    @Column(name="descripcionBreveONG")
    String descripcionBreveONG;
    @Column(name="descripcionONG")
    String descripcionONG;
    @Column(name="idiomaONG")
    int idiomaONG;






    public ONG() {
    }

    public ONG(Long idONG, String nombreONG,  String urlONG,
            String descripcionBreveONG, String descripcionONG, int idiomaONG) {
        super();
        this.idONG = idONG;
        this.nombreONG = nombreONG;
        this.identificadoresONG = new ArrayList<Identificador>();
        this.urlONG = urlONG;
        this.descripcionBreveONG = descripcionBreveONG;
        this.descripcionONG = descripcionONG;
        this.idiomaONG = idiomaONG;
    }

    public ONG(Long idONG, String nombreONG, List<Identificador> identificadoresONG, String urlONG,
            String descripcionBreveONG, String descripcionONG, int idiomaONG) {
        super();
        this.idONG = idONG;
        this.nombreONG = nombreONG;
        this.identificadoresONG = identificadoresONG;
        this.urlONG = urlONG;
        this.descripcionBreveONG = descripcionBreveONG;
        this.descripcionONG = descripcionONG;
        this.idiomaONG = idiomaONG;
    }



    public ONG( String nombreONG, String urlONG,
            String descripcionBreveONG, String descripcionONG, int idiomaONG) {
        this.nombreONG = nombreONG;
        this.identificadoresONG = new ArrayList<Identificador>();
        this.urlONG = urlONG;
        this.descripcionBreveONG = descripcionBreveONG;
        this.descripcionONG = descripcionONG;
        this.idiomaONG = idiomaONG;
    }
    public ONG(String nombreONG, String urlONG ) {
        this.nombreONG=nombreONG;
        this.urlONG=urlONG;
        this.identificadoresONG=new ArrayList<Identificador>();
        this.descripcionBreveONG="";
        this.descripcionONG="";
        this.idiomaONG=1;
    }       
}
```

**Tienda**

```
package com.aiddonAPI.tienda;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.*;
import com.aiddonAPI.identificador.Identificador;

@Table(name="tiendas")
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name="SequenceTienda", initialValue=0)
public class Tienda implements Serializable{
    @GeneratedValue(generator="SecuenceTienda") 
    @Id
    @Column(name="idTienda")
    Long idTienda;
    @Column(name="nombreTienda", unique=true)
    String nombreTienda;
    @Column(name="urlTienda")
    String urlTienda;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="tienda")
    List<Identificador> identificadoresTienda;
    @Column(name="descripcionBrveTienda")
    String descripcionBreveTienda;
    @Column(name="descripcionTienda")
    String descripcionTienda;
    @Column(name="idiomaTienda")
    int idiomaTienda;







    public Tienda() {}



    public Tienda( String nombreTienda, String urlTienda, String descripcionBreveTienda, String descripcionTienda, int idiomaTienda) {
        super();
        this.nombreTienda = nombreTienda;
        this.urlTienda=urlTienda;
        this.identificadoresTienda =new ArrayList<Identificador>();
        this.descripcionBreveTienda = descripcionBreveTienda;
        this.descripcionTienda = descripcionTienda;
        this.idiomaTienda = idiomaTienda;
    }       
}
```

**Identificador**

```
package com.aiddonAPI.identificador;



import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import com.aiddonAPI.ong.ONG;
import com.aiddonAPI.tienda.Tienda;
@Table(name="identificadores")
@Entity 
@SequenceGenerator(name="SequenceIdentificador", initialValue=0)
public class Identificador implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="SequenceIdentificador")
    @Column(name="idIdentificador")
    Long idIdentificador;

    Long ong;
    Long tienda;

    @Column(name="identificadorONG")
    String identificadorONG;
    @Column(name="identificadorTienda")
    String identificadorTienda;
    @Column(name="agencia")
    int agencia;

    public Identificador() {};
    public Identificador(Long idIdentificador, ONG ong, Tienda tienda, String identificadorONG,
            String identificadorTienda, int agencia) {
        this.idIdentificador = idIdentificador;
        this.ong = ong.getIdONG();
        this.tienda = tienda.getIdTienda();
        this.identificadorONG = identificadorONG;
        this.identificadorTienda = identificadorTienda;
        this.agencia = agencia;
    }

    public Identificador(ONG ong, Tienda tienda, String identificadorONG, String identificadorTienda, int agencia) {
        this.ong = ong.getIdONG();
        this.tienda = tienda.getIdTienda();
        this.identificadorONG = identificadorONG;
        this.identificadorTienda = identificadorTienda;
        this.agencia = agencia;
    }
}
```

El caso es que puedo crear un identificador sin problemas. Este identificador se añade sin problemas a la clase Tienda sin problema alguno, de modo que si recupero hago una petición a la API preguntando por una tienda la API me devuelve la la tienda con su lista de identificadores sin problema alguno. El problema viene cuando lo que hago es pedirle a la API por alguna petición que me devuelva una ONG, la lista de identificadores de esa ONG me la devuelve siempre vacía y la verdad es que no le encuentro explicación.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Has probado usar el mismo @mapped que usas entre tienda y tu lista de identificadores,  para ong con esa misma lista??

Answer (score 1):

No uso `spring` pero en `JPA` cuando se tiene una relación `uno-a-muchos` se deben de anotar las dos clases que se relacionan, así la clase `Tienda.java` tiene uno o varios objetos de tipo `Identificador.java` por lo cual esta última tiene un atributo `List` de tipo `Identificador` (`List<Identificador> nombreAtributo;`) el cual tiene la anotación `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "tienda")`, pero este atributo, en la clase `Identificador.java` debería se de tipo `Tienda.java`y debe estar anotana con @ManyToOne() y @JoinColumn(name="identificadorTienda") donde `identificadorTienda` es el nombre del campo en la tabla `identificadores` de la BD, que hace referencia a una tienda (llave foranea).

```
@Table(name="identificadores")
@Entity 
@SequenceGenerator(name="SequenceIdentificador", initialValue=0)
public class Identificador implements Serializable{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator="SequenceIdentificador")
  @Column(name="idIdentificador")
  Long idIdentificador;
  Long ong;

  @JoinColumn(name = "identificadorTienda")
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  Tienda tienda;

  @Column(name="identificadorONG")
  String identificadorONG;

  @Column(name="agencia")
  int agencia;

  //Demas código
}
```

Ahora para crear un Identificador nuevo y asociarlo a una Tienda ya existente se debe de:

1. Obtener el objeto `Tienda` al cual se le va asociar un nuevo identificador.
2. Crear el nuevo objeto `Identificador`, a este se le debe pasar el objeto tienda consultado (por constructor o por método `setTienda(Tienda tienda)`).
3. Adicionar el nuevo identificador a la **lista de identificadores** de la tienda a través del método `Tienda.getIdentificadores().add(nuevoIdentificador)`
4. A través del reposotorio de Tienda, hacer un `update` o `merge` de la tienda obtenida en el punto 1

De esta forma al consultar una tienda se obtendran los identificadores asociados y al consultar un identificador sepuede consultar la tienda.